# Task Scheduler run Jupyter Notebook script

Tags: python

I use Jupyter Notebook for python development because of the modularity the cells give me. However, I need to schedule my scripts (with the task scheduler).
So, what I currently do is download my .ipynb to .py so I can schedule them. However, this messes up my control version system and I need to do duplicate work. Is there a way I could have the best of both worlds? (Modularity, ease of use, ability to schedule and version control).

Answer (score 0):

Please check [JupyText](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) package to keep .py file synchronized with .ipynb.

The other approach is to schedule the ipynb file directly. There are many ways to [schedule Jupyter Notebook](https://mljar.com/blog/schedule-jupyter-notebook/). You can use [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert) or [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) to execute the notebook with corn or Windows Task Scheduler. If you are looking for a web-based solution for scheduling and sharing notebooks, you can try [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) or [Notebooker](https://github.com/man-group/notebooker).